# jQuery: Select all parents of the selected LI element

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a hierarchical UL list. How to - using jQuery - get the all parents of the selected LI element and change the `<a>`'s background color inside each parent ?

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">A</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">B</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">B1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B3</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">B4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">C</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">C1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

If I e.g. select `<a href="#">B4</a>`, `<a href="#">B</a>` and `<a href="#">A</a>` will be also selected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will bind a `click` event to all `<li>` elements, and literally apply a background color to all parents and itself.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).parents().andSelf().css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

jQuery docs:

- [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)
- [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)

Comment: Also, if you want to stop matching at a certain point, you can use [`parentsUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/): `$(this).parentsUntil('#container-to-not-include').andSelf().css('background','red');`.

Comment: hmm, I've tested this code and everyghing has changed its background. I'm trying to achieve that only the text (<a>) has the Red background, not whole LI and UL

Comment: That's a whole different question. In your case, you have to traverse the tree: `$(this).parents('ul').each(function(){$(this).prev('a').css('background-color','red');});`. This method selects every `<a>` **right before** one of the parent `<ul>` elements. If you also want to change the colour of the `<a>` child inside the clicked `<li>`, also add `$(this).children('a').css('background-color','red');`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both A and B are `UL` elements, the following code should work:

```
$(this).parents('ul').addClass('new_class');
```